# How to have a key to close a program while not focused

Tags: python

-- Auto-Clicker Program --

Hi, i have been writing this program and have run into the issue, that when i run it that i can't close it due to the fact that it's not focused when i'm using it, I have been testing this program on the game Cookie Clicker for a real test.

```
import win32api
import win32con
import msvcrt


def click(x, y): 
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0,  0)

# 27 = esc | 13 = enter | 80 = down arrow | 72 = up arrow

counter = 0
try:
    while counter < 20000:
         click(230, 470)
         if msvcrt.kbhit() and ord(msvcrt.getch()) == 27:
             print("abort")
             break
         counter += 1
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

I have had no luck in finding a way in having it so that i can bind a key to kill the program and such that i can kill it while not focused on it, sort of like a global hotkey.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try [GetKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Detecting Key Presses using win32api in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592500/detecting-key-presses-using-win32api-in-python)

With what Kevin said i looked up GetKeyState.

and now this is working...

```
import win32api
import win32con


def click(x, y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0,  0)

counter = 0
try:
    while counter < 50000:
        click(230, 475)

        if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(ord('H')):
            break
        counter += 1
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```