# How to pass functions without having the console open in Python

Tags: python, hotkeys, keylogger, getch

So I've been playing with Getch recently. So let's say we do something like this...

```
from msvcrt import getch

while True:
    key = ord(getch())
    if key == 27: #ESC
        print ("Value Read")
        break
    elif key == 13: #Enter
        select()
    elif key == 224: #Special keys (arrows, f keys, ins, del, etc.)
        key = ord(getch())
        if key == 80: #Down arrow
            moveDown()
        elif key == 72: #Up arrow
            moveUp()
```

What I would like to do is have the Python console read the input such that I don't have to have the Python console as my active window. Does anybody know how to do this as it looks like "getch" just looks for input in the console (this isn't what I was looking for and I'm not sure if this is possible in Python).

Thank you for your time and consideration,

mmacheerpuppy

Comment: You might want to check this code, for educational purposes :) https://github.com/ajinabraham/Xenotix-Python-Keylogger

Comment: Thank you I'll have a read of this on lunch break ;) <3

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use win32api as a wrapper to GetAsyncKeyState

have a look a more detailed answer about this in:

[Detecting Key Presses using win32api in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592500/detecting-key-presses-using-win32api-in-python)

Comment: Thank you! I look forward to having a look at this. Currently in the process of trying to turn my python passion into a career.