# How to access keyboard state in python (on Windows) without the script being the active window?

Tags: python

What I'm trying to figure out right now is how to use a python script to record a keypress if the active window is an emulator. Every solution I've found requires the active window to be script which contains the keypress detector. Any idea on how to access system keyboard state in windows without it being the active window?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting Key Presses using win32api in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592500/detecting-key-presses-using-win32api-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

this solution uses the `pynput` library

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(
        key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: This works exactly how I wanted it to, thank you so much!