# How to change driver level keyboard interaction?(using Python or C++)

Tags: python, c++, keyboard, ctypes, pywin32

I am beginner level in programming(less than a year of experience). I am trying to use https://github.com/Sentdex/pygta5/blob/master/directkeys.py to imitate keyboard inputs in one of RPGs. I successfully managed to implement simple movements(WASD) but when I try to use game specific command as example "choose a closest enemy(Using TAB)" game doesn't react to the input. By doing some research I realized that the game most likely have internal driver level keyboard interaction which cannot be activated using Direct Inputs. I am asking for possible ways to solve the issue.

I tried to use virtual keys to try to imitate the keyboard inputs. Also, I tried to reassign one of the movement keys to "chose closest enemy button" but it produces no inputs as well. I am might start extensive research towards even lower-level keyboard interactions and see what I can do from there.

Here is small code sample

```
from directkeys import KeyPress, PressKey, ReleaseKey, W, ESC, C, TAB
import time
import win32gui

# open a window
handle = win32gui.FindWindow(0, "Game window")
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(handle)

# Press and Release key
PressKey(W) 
time.sleep(3)
ReleaseKey(W)

print("Script finished")
```

Comment: There is low level keyboard hooks but it seems what you're trying to achieve is very easily doable by calling GetAsyncKeyState from the Windows API https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592500/detecting-key-presses-using-win32api-in-python

Comment: @Nina Thank you for your response, but I am trying to make the game register the key press and not just verify that it was pressed. Also, I tried GetAsyncKeyState and it returns 1 but nothing happens inside the game. Both Virtual Keys and Direct keys work for movement commands but does not work for game specific commands.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. As in you're trying to send a key or simulate a key stroke in the game itself? If that's the case, you can use the SendInput windows API. Or the keybd_event but Microsoft recommends SendInput. There are plenty of tutorials on how to use SendInput with Python.

Comment: has solve？ i need to driver level keyboard