# How to implement a non blocking keyboard event listener?

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, events, python-asyncio

How would someone implement a simple program that listens to keyboard input and runs another function when a specific button is pressed with only native Python 3?

I would imagine it is something like this:

```
import asyncio, ctypes

async def printme():
    print('Hello World')

async def main():
   if ctypes.windll.user32.GetKeyState(0x7B)>>15: #Pressing F12
      await printme()

asyncio.run(main())
```

But as you see this will only run once... quite confused as to how to make this indefinite without it running in an infinite while loop (must be event driven without GUI programming).

edit: Also forgot to mention, what even is considered a key press? Is it the moment when the key in question is in a DOWN state or does a press not count until it has been through the DOWN then UP cycle? Specifically referring to

`if ctypes.windll.user32.GetKeyState(0x7B)` as I don't even know if this is truly "a key press".

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592500/detecting-key-presses-using-win32api-in-python

Comment: You're asking how to reinvent [RegisterHotKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey).