# Can't trigger clicks while using Left Button in win32api with pyautogui

Tags: python, winapi, pyautogui

If you test that code you'll see that you can't click and wait for a press on the same key(it's left mouse button in this case, 0x01 is for left)

see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

If you put 0x02 and pyautogui(button='right') that's the same problem

```
import pyautogui 

import win32api 


while True: 
    if win32api.GetKeyState(0x01) < 0: # it doesn't work with 0x01 but if you replace it by 0x02 or any other key it will work and want it to work with 0x01 that's the problem
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.1 
        pyautogui.click()
```

why ? That's impossible to do ???
Should I use another thing ? pynput or win32api (for the generated clicks)

Comment: Why did you add the `tkinter` tag to this question? I suggest adding the `pyautogui` and `winapi` tags instead.

Comment: The documentation for [`GetKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate) explains this.

Comment: it's done, but how I can achieve this ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: -IInspectable Where ???

Comment: – 
ellhe-blaster I can assure you that I have explained my problem with the little code above. If you enter any key to press the left click of the mouse will click but if the waiting key is the left click it will not work and I ask why

Comment: plz help me I really need that :(

Comment: It says right [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate#remarks): *"The key status returned from this function changes as a thread reads key messages from its message queue."* Your code doesn't.

Comment: so i should use GetAsyncKeyState right ?

Comment: That's not going to help. You'll have to understand the system you are targeting. See [When something gets added to a queue, it takes time for it to come out the front of the queue](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773), for example.

Answer (score -1):

About `GetAsyncKeyState`, you also can refer to this thread [Detecting Key Presses using win32api in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592500/detecting-key-presses-using-win32api-in-python).

It is recommended that you use `pyhook` or `pynput`.

```
hm = pyHook.HookManager()

hm.MouseAll = onMouseEvent

hm.HookMouse()

pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: It is recommended to choose one of pynput and pyhook.

Comment: That doesn't even remotely attempt to answer the question that is being asked.